# Why is 'use strict'; in node generating a call stack but no error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a [hapi.js](http://spumko.github.io/) node app and whenever I enabled 'use strict' globally, node won't start and it just dumps out this stack trace with no error:

```
Object.exports.callStack (/Users/me/my_app/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:342:47),Object.internals.getSourceFilePath
(Users/me/my_app/node_modules/hapi/lib/pack.js:541:23),internals.Pack.require
(Users/me/myapp/node_modules/hapi/lib/pack.js:456:32),Object.scoped.require
(Users/me/my_app/node_modules/hapi/lib/pack.js:605:18),module.exports
(Users/me/my_app/config/packs.js:2:36),Object.
(Users/me/my_app/index.js:7:38),Module.compile 
(module.js:456:26),Object.Module.extensions..js (module.js:474:10),Module.load (module.js:356:32),Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Obviously, something in [hoek](https://github.com/spumko/hoek) is triggering a 'use strict' error - but why isn't node telling me what the actual error is so I can identify and file an issue?

I should mention that we're applying 'use strict' app-wide by requiring the [use-strict](https://github.com/isaacs/use-strict) module, which is just three lines that does this:

```
var module = require('module')
module.wrapper[0] += '"use strict";'
Object.freeze(module.wrap)
```

Comment: Alternative suggestion: any JS code you write should have "use strict" anyway, you shouldn't leave it implied. Then, rather than relying on the use-strict module, use grunt and set up a jshint task so that your code gets checked when you run the grunt command.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This isn't my code. It's a node_module that is triggering the issue. I agree with you in general; however, I have lost that particular argument with my team.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible minimal example?